# Problem with storing values in multiple textboxes

Tags: 7, services

I'm having problem while storing values in multiple text-boxes, its stores value only in 1st text-box, here i'm using following JSON format of drupal 7 services.

```
"field_raoster_travel_time":{"und":[{"value":"8"},{"value":"81"}]}
```

( Note : I have set "Number of values" : "Unlimited" for text-box )

[image: Unlimited text box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a field is set to `Unlimited values`, Drupal Services does not yet properly support them. There is an [open issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224803) here, and a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224803#comment-11477609) in progress that I've used multiple times to get around this limitation. Grab the latest development version of Drupal Services 7.x-3.x and apply the patch mentioned above, and that should fix it.

Comment: Patch is working, issue resolved.